# CKModifyRecordsOperation error retry logic

Tags: swift, cloudkit, nsoperation, ckerror

I am new to CloudKit and have figured out `CKModifyRecordsOperation` with basic cases of add/remove/delete of one `CKRecord` at a time.  I want to use it to pass in multiple `recordsToSave` and `recordIDsToDelete`.  I know that I need to do a retry when `error.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey]` has a value. My question is, how do I retry this operation?  I am stuck figuring out how to know what records to retry.  Do I have to retry all records?  Which completion block can I do a retry in, or is it both?

My code is below with comments where I don't understand how to retry.

```
func modifyCkRecs(recsToAddOrMod: [CKRecord]?, recordIDsToDelete:[CKRecordID]?, numTries: Int) {


let ops = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: recsToAddOrMod, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete)
ops.savePolicy = CKRecordSavePolicy.AllKeys

ops.perRecordCompletionBlock =  { record, error in

  if let error = error {

    var message = error.localizedDescription
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.NotAuthenticated.rawValue {
      print("Not authenticated")
      message = "If you want your data the same on all your Apple devices, then log into iCloud on your device and make sure the iCloud drive is turned on for this app.\nTo enable iCloud, go to Settings -> iCloud"
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.ServiceUnavailable.rawValue {
      print("Service unavailable")
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.RequestRateLimited.rawValue {
      print("Request Rate Limited")
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.NetworkFailure.rawValue {
      print("Network failure!!")
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.InvalidArguments.rawValue {
      print("Invalid Arguments!!")
    }
    print("Error msg: \(message)")

//        if let delayTime = self.retryTime(error) {
//          if numTries < CloudKitAPI.MAX_RETRY {
//            
//            dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
//              self.modifyCkRecs(????,????, numTries: numTries+1)
//            }
//          }
//          else {
//            print("WARNING: Reached MAX number of retry, giving up")
//          }
//        }
  }
  else {
    print("Update was a success!")
    if let updatedRec = record {
      if let coreDataObj = self.convertRecToCoreData(updatedRec) {
        // archive the CKRecord system fields into Core Data
        coreDataObj.archiveCkMetadata(updatedRec)

        // remove from queue
        self.addedOrModQueue.removeValueForKey(coreDataObj.uuid)
        self.saveAMQueue()
      }
    }
  }
}

// TODO: Figure out what this block is good for
ops.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
  if let error = error {

    var message = error.localizedDescription
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.NotAuthenticated.rawValue {
      print("Not authenticated")
      message = "If you want your data the same on all your Apple devices, then log into iCloud on your device and make sure the iCloud drive is turned on for this app.\nTo enable iCloud, go to Settings -> iCloud"
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.ServiceUnavailable.rawValue {
      print("Service unavailable")
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.RequestRateLimited.rawValue {
      print("Request Rate Limited")
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.NetworkFailure.rawValue {
      print("Network failure!!")
    }
    if error.code == CKErrorCode.InvalidArguments.rawValue {
      print("Invalid Arguments!!")
    }
    print("Error msg: \(message)")

    // RETRY LOGIC HERE????
    // SOMETHING LIKE THE ABOVE BUT WITH THESE ARGS:
    // self.modifyCkRecs(recsToAddOrMod, recordIDsToDelete, numTries: numTries+1)
  }
  else {

    // clean up the deleted queue
    if let deletedRecs = deletedRecordIDs {
      for deletedRecId in deletedRecs {
        if let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: deletedRecId.recordName), let index = self.deletedQueue.indexOf(uuid) {
          self.deletedQueue.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
      }
      self.saveDQueue()
    }
  }
}

ops.qualityOfService = .Background
privateDB.addOperation(ops)
}
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270295/cloudkit-error-handling-retry-logic)? Doesn't my answer (that you accepted just before posting this) to that question answer this one?

Comment: I thought about adding it to that question, but wasn't sure about the SO etiquette on that.  Since I felt the last one was answered, I didn't want to modify it.  This question is about multiple records at a time.  In particular 1) Do I have to retry with ALL the records even if some succeed?  2) Which completion block should the retry go into?

Comment: If you get any of the errors you posted in the question then you have to retry all of them. If you get a `partialFailure` then you have to dig deep into the dictionary of error info to determine what to do next.

Comment: That helps thanks, I guess I will have to watch out to not duplicate modify logic on retry.  Do you have any insight on which completion block retry logic should go?  `CKModifyRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock` or `CKModifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock`  And does it depend on the error code found?